# How can I get rid of input suggestion?

Tags: html, css, text, input, search-suggestion

How to get rid of the suggestion box that appears if you double click on the `input` field.
`autocomplete="off"` does not work.
[Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggGfv.png)

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: on chrome safari and firefox does this problem exsist

Comment: Browsers ignore `autocomplete="off"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `autocomplete="off"`

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: no i tried it does not work i added a picture in my question is does not disapear. i want to get rid of that box it shows when i double click on the box